# Extract ValueXml in Pl

Tags: oracle

I have extracted
EXTRACTVALUE(v_xml,'/rss/channel/item/title')
**"2018-07-19"**

i want to extract all "description" values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>RSS NBG Currency Rates</title>
<link>https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=236&amp;lang=geo</link>
<description>Currency Rates</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</lastBuildDate>
<managingEditor>alex@proservice.ge</managingEditor>
<webMaster>alex@proservice.ge</webMaster>
<item>
     <title>2018-07-19</title>
 <link>https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=236&amp;lang=geo</link>
 <description><![CDATA[<table border="0"><tr>
            <td>AED</td>
            <td>6.6828</td>
            <td>0.0158</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>ZAR</td>
            <td>1.8412</td>
            <td>0.0032</td>
        </tr></table>]]></description>
 <pubDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</pubDate>
 <guid>https://</guid>
</item>
</channel></rss>;
```

Comment: Are you sure you should posting real URLs and email addresses? And what is "Pl" - do you mean PL/SQL, and if does it need to be in PL/SQL rather than just SQL? Also, which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extractvalue` function is deprecated. You could use separate XMLQuery calls instead, or you could get both the title and description with XMLTable:

```
select *
from xmltable('/rss/channel/item'
  passing xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>RSS NBG Currency Rates</title>
<link>https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=236&amp;lang=geo</link>
<description>Currency Rates</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</lastBuildDate>
<managingEditor>alex@proservice.ge</managingEditor>
<webMaster>alex@proservice.ge</webMaster>
<item>
     <title>2018-07-19</title>
 <link>https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=236&amp;lang=geo</link>
 <description><![CDATA[<table border="0"><tr>
            <td>AED</td>
            <td>6.6828</td>
            <td>0.0158</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>ZAR</td>
            <td>1.8412</td>
            <td>0.0032</td>
        </tr></table>]]></description>
 <pubDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</pubDate>
 <guid>https://</guid>
</item>
</channel></rss>')
  columns title varchar2(30) path 'title',
    description varchar2(4000) path 'description'
);
```

which gets

```
TITLE                          DESCRIPTION                                       
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------
2018-07-19                     <table border="0"><tr>                            
                                           <td>AED</td>                          
                                           <td>6.6828</td>                       
                                           <td>0.0158</td>                       
                                       </tr><tr>                                 
                                           <td>ZAR</td>                          
                                           <td>1.8412</td>                       
                                           <td>0.0032</td>                       
                                       </tr></table>
```

This is passing the XML as a string literal, if you already have it as an XMLType them you don't need the conversion `xmltype('<string>')`, soif you `v_xml` is a PL/SQL XMLType variable then:

```
select title, description
into v_title, v_description -- use your own PL/SQL variable names
from xmltable('/rss/channel/item'
  passing v_xml
  columns title varchar2(30) path 'title',
    description varchar2(200) path 'description'
);
```

If it is a string (`varchar2` or `CLOB`) then you still need to convert it:

```
select title, description
into v_title, v_description -- use your own PL/SQL variable names
from xmltable('/rss/channel/item'
  passing xmltype(v_xml)
  columns title varchar2(30) path 'title',
    description varchar2(200) path 'description'
);
```

You can extract other data by adding more entries to the `columns` clause.

---

If - and it's a big 'if' - the CDATA section is always going to be the same format, with well-formed CDATA and HTML with a table with three columns, then you can treat the HTML table as XML (this often isn't safe though) and extract the individual values with another XMLTable:

```
select x1.title, x2.col1, x2.col2, x2.col3
from xmltable('/rss/channel/item'
  passing xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>RSS NBG Currency Rates</title>
<link>https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=236&amp;lang=geo</link>
<description>Currency Rates</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</lastBuildDate>
<managingEditor>alex@proservice.ge</managingEditor>
<webMaster>alex@proservice.ge</webMaster>
<item>
     <title>2018-07-19</title>
 <link>https://www.nbg.gov.ge/index.php?m=236&amp;lang=geo</link>
 <description><![CDATA[<table border="0"><tr>
            <td>AED</td>
            <td>6.6828</td>
            <td>0.0158</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>ZAR</td>
            <td>1.8412</td>
            <td>0.0032</td>
        </tr></table>]]></description>
 <pubDate>Thu, 19 Jul 2018 14:10:50 +0400</pubDate>
 <guid>https://</guid>
</item>
</channel></rss>')
  columns title varchar2(30) path 'title',
    description clob path 'description'
) x1
cross join xmltable('/table/tr'
  passing xmltype(x1.description)
  columns col1 varchar2(10) path 'td[1]',
    col2 varchar2(20) path 'td[2]',
    col3 varchar2(20) path 'td[3]'
) x2;
```

which gets:

```
TITLE                          COL1       COL2                 COL3                
------------------------------ ---------- -------------------- --------------------
2018-07-19                     AED        6.6828               0.0158              
2018-07-19                     ZAR        1.8412               0.0032
```

Be aware though that HTML <> XML and in general you can't parse HTML like this. There are other tolls to do that though.

Comment: can you help me to transform   DESCRIPTION          part to table?

Comment: @teimurazMamukashvili - I've added a way to do that for CDATA formatted as you have shown, but it's fragile. If the description format changes then this will have to be modified, and it's feasible you could get something that can't be treated as XML at all.